# Why is fixed background image on chrome not working?

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

The position of a background image in CSS is not working in chrome. The fixed position works on FireFox but not in Chrome

An example is at http://gravitylab.nz the top background (picture with the cellphone) is fixed and working in Firefox.

When I open it in Chrome and it doesn't stay fixed.

The inline CSS for row containing background-image is something like this:

```
background: transparent url(http://gravitylab.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/WJDK7M84F9.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
```

Comment: I have the same issue on my website. Did you tried to add -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); ?